# customize onclick confirm message based on link parameters

Tags: jquery, confirm

I have multiple links :

```
<a href="validation/object_1/" class="validation">Validate</a>
<a href="validation/object_2/" class="validation">Validate</a>
```

object_n is dynamically defined

I want to ask the user to confirm he wants to validate this object

something like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.validation').on('click', function () {
    return confirm('Are you sure tou want to validate this "object_name" ?');
});
```

how can I customize the confirmation message with object name = object_1 for the first link and object_2 for the second link ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `.attr()` and get the href
2. Use `.split()` to ge the needed string

```js
$('.validation').on('click', function() {
  return confirm('Are you sure tou want to validate this ' + $(this).attr('href').split("/")[1] + ' ?');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="validation/object_1/" class="validation">Validate</a>
<a href="validation/object_2/" class="validation">Validate</a>
```

Comment: thanks @guradio What a speed !, I was still editing my question and you had already given your answers :)

Comment: @BrigitteCharpent no problem mate glad to help happy coding

Comment: Finally, my html is a bit different : the class is defined outside the href :

<div class="validation">
<a href="validation/object_1/" >Validate</a>
</div>

and your code doesn't work with my html. I don't know if I should modify the jquery code to fit to this html ?

Comment: use `$('.validation > a')` i means select the anchor tag that is direct child of element with class validation

Comment: perfects, thanks. and for those with the same nees here is  the documentation for jquery selectors : https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp